# SharePoint Default View Ignores Custom Title DisplayName

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, wss-3.0

I've created a custom content type that inherits from a contact (i.e. <ContentType ID="0x010600...") and I'm trying to rename the "Title" field using the following:

```
<FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" DisplayName="Last Name" Sealed="TRUE"  />
    <FieldRef ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Last Name" Sealed="TRUE"/>
    <FieldRef ID="{BC91A437-52E7-49E1-8C4E-4698904B2B6D}" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" DisplayName="Last Name" Sealed="TRUE" />
</FieldRefs>
```

It renames correctly in the Edit, View, and Add pages, but in the default view and DataGrid view it always says title.  I want it renamed everywhere.  Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so how?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the field to be renamed in view you have to define your list using a ListTemplate and repeat your renaming of the fields in here (as well as the annoying repeating all of the fields from your content type which isn't standard)